# Parse json with javascript

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have this json file I want parse and get value of `subcat` for `test1` as an array in javascript. Is there an easy way to do this? I have used AngularJS `$http` to get the json.

For the input:

```
[
   {
    "category":"test1",
    "ID":"1",
      "subcat":[
        {
         "completed":"4",
         "uncompleted":"5"
        }
     ]
   },{
    "category":"test2",
    "ID":"2"
    "subcat":[
        {
         "completed":"1",
         "uncompleted":"5"
        }
   }

]
```

Expected result is `[4,5]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

```
Corrected Array 


 [
       {
         "category":"test1",
          "subcat":[
                    {
                      "completed":"4",
                      "uncompleted":"5"
                     }
                   ]
       },
       {
          "category":"test2",
          "subcat":[
                    {
                      "completed":"1",
                      "uncompleted":"5"
                    }
                   ]
         }
    ]
var JsonArray=[
                {
                  "category":"test1",
                  "subcat":[{"completed":"4","uncompleted":"5"}]}, 
                {
                  "category":"test2",
                  "subcat":[{"completed":"1","uncompleted":"5"}]
                }
              ];
for(var i=0;i<JsonArray.length;i++)
      {
          if(JsonArray[i].category=="test1")
            var Res=JsonArray[i].subcat;
      }
```

"Res" will contain your desired result;
If you want array as [4,5]
Then

```
var finalRes=[];
finalRes.push(Res[0].completed);
finalRes.push(Res[0].uncompleted);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
      var newarray=new Array();
var test='[{"category":"test1","ID":"1","subcat":[{"completed":"4","uncompleted":"5"}]},{"category":"test2","ID":"2","subcat":[{"completed":"1","uncompleted":"5"}]}]';

var tags = JSON.parse(test);

for(i=0;i<tags.length;i++)
{

if(tags[i]['category']=='test1')
{
var subcat=tags[i]['subcat'];
for(j=0;j<subcat.length;j++)
{
newarray.push(subcat[j]['completed']);
newarray.push(subcat[j]['uncompleted']);
}

}
}
console.log(newarray);
      </script>
```

Output:["4", "5"]

DEMO:https://jsfiddle.net/t4yfb923/

Comment: I posted my answer check it and let me know

Answer (score -1):

You can use lodash and the method find :
https://lodash.com/docs#find

```
// Stock your json in a variable
var json = [
   {
    "category":"test1",
    "ID":"1",
      "subcat":[
        {
         "completed":"4",
         "uncompleted":"5"
        }
     ]
   },{
    "category":"test2",
    "ID":"2"
    "subcat":[
        {
         "completed":"1",
         "uncompleted":"5"
        }
   }

]

//find your object with lodash
var result = _.find(json, {"ID": "1"});

//then, get subcat value
console.log(result.subcat)
```